# Adding spark-installer to path with zsh

Tags: laravel, zsh, oh-my-zsh, laravel-spark

I'm using zsh with oh-my-zsh as my shell and I need to add the Laravel Spark Installer to my path, but I must be missing a step or messing up the syntax

I've added spark-installer to my path like this:

```
path+=('/Users/retrograde/Development/spark-installer')
```

Nothing was added to the path, so I edited it directly with:

```
vim ~/.zshrc
```

added

```
   # Spark installer
  export PATH="$HOME/Users/retrograde/Development/spark-installer:$PATH"
```

then ran:

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

The spark-installer does not show with the other paths upon running  echo "$PATH"

Am I missing something?  Maybe my syntax is wrong?  TIA

Comment: are you sure. I just tried the same syntax in my .zshrc file . and I can see the spark-installer in the PATH. It will be in the beginning of the path.

Comment: maybe I'm not resetting it correctly?   source ~/.zshrc  is it, right?

Comment: this is my echo "$PATH" output: /Users/retrograde/.composer/vendor/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin

Comment: instead of sourcing close the terminal and open a new one and check path there. also what is the output of `echo $0`

Comment: Ok, that worked it is in the path now.   echo $0 returns /bin/zsh.    But when I try to run a spark command, I still get: zsh: command not found: spark

Comment: where is your larvel installed ?

Comment: Globally, using:  composer global require "laravel/installer", the project is going to be in the users/retograde/Development  folder

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129960/discussion-between-root545-and-retrograde).